# Stretch font vertically/horizontally whilst conforming to curve in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, cs6, transform, scale

So I'm trying to make my text shorter (less height), but transforming it won't do since it would warp the curvature of the text as well.

Example:

[image: Examp]

Comment: Welcome! A couple questions to assist in answers --- 1) Is it "live" editable text or artwork that *looks* like text? 2) How was the curve created? These factors will **greatly** determine any answers. Please [edit](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/158990/edit) the question with more information. Thanks!

Comment: Is this for editable text on a path?  If so, you can [change the vertical scale](https://imgur.com/DdwqSKk) of the text in the Character panel.

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyKH9.jpg The answer is to edit this property in the character tab. The reason I asked this question in the first place was because I was unable to find any article on this property on Google, so I did not even know it existed. Thanks, @BillyKerr